# Error 403 Py-cord guild_ids for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, pycord

```
@bot.slash_command(name="askgpt", description="Ask a question to AI!")
@option(
    "Inquiry",
    description="Ask something!",
    required=True,
)
async def askgpt(
        ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
        inquiry: str
):
    if client.shard_id == '772141234940018688':
        pass
    else:
        await ctx.respond('Command not enabled.')

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[

            {"role": "system", "content": f'Answer this question, {inquiry}, using as few words as possible.'},
            {"role": "user", "content": f'Answer the question, {inquiry}, using as few words as possible.'}
            ])
    await ctx.respond(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
```

When I put the guild_ids argument in the @bot.slash_command block, I got a 403 Forbidden error in my console. My bot has application.commands and bot oauth perms.

initially, I tried to use the guild_ids='' argument in the @bot.slash.command() line to limit the slash command to one user (me). After running the code, I got a 403 forbidden/ code 50001 no access error in my console.

In the code I provided along with this message, I tried to use a sort of gateway to block the code from running if the user is not me. I don't think it works as intended, as the response  block from openai is still active. What can I do to fix the errors, or possibly make my "roadblock" code work?

Comment: If you want to restrict the command, why not check if the ID of the command author matches your ID?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running that code through **guild_ids=[...]** parameter and it works for me. 403 error means that your bot is not in the guild whose id you have put in the parameter. Hence it shows missing access. Make sure you have the right ID and your bot is in the server.

This should work for you:

```
@client.slash_command(name="askgpt", description="Ask a question to AI!",guild_ids = [772141234940018688])
@option(
  "Inquiry",
  description="Ask something!",
  required=True,
)
async def askgpt(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    inquiry: str
):
```

Otherwise, if you want to check the guild id, you can use ctx to find the guild id and compare it like this:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="askgpt", description="Ask a question to AI!")
@option(
    "Inquiry",
    description="Ask something!",
    required=True,
)
async def askgpt(
        ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
        inquiry: str
):
    if ctx.guild.id == 772141234940018688: #used ctx and got rid of quotation marks as ctx.guild.id returns the id in int type and not str type
        pass
    else:
        await ctx.respond('Command not enabled.')
        return #to end the execution of command otherwise it will come out of this statement and execute the remaining code. Alternatively you could put all the remaining code inside the if statement itself.


    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[

            {"role": "system", "content": f'Answer this question, {inquiry}, using as few words as possible.'},
            {"role": "user", "content": f'Answer the question, {inquiry}, using as few words as possible.'}
            ])
    await ctx.respond(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
```

I'd advice you to put the remaining lines after the if-else statement inside the if statement itself instead of just putting pass.

Let me know if you run into any more errors or need more explanation about anything!!